# How to have ripple effect propagate throughout entire rectangle (For Android 6)

Tags: android

Currently, I would like to have a proper ripple effect for my rectangle card.

The ripple effect I can achieve, is a small circle, which only propagate within a small click region.

### Video captured at Android 6

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zeBFqVPS38

However, I realize in Android 5, with same set of code, the ripple can cover entire rectangle region.

### Video captured at Android 5

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEkb-7TDI7k

---

How can I have a ripple effect, which propagates throughout my entire rectangle card? Or, I shouldn't have this expectation under Android 6?

### Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/lift_up"
    android:background="?attr/newsRowLayoutSelector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="?attr/newsTitleTextViewSelector"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="?attr/newsDescriptionTextViewColor"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="?attr/newsDateTextViewColor"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### Background selector (?attr/newsRowLayoutSelector)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/news_card_ripple_material_light">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/news_card_material_light" />
</ripple>
```

### @drawable/news_card_material_light

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/news_card_material_light" />
</shape>
```

These are the color being used.

```
<color name="news_card_material_light">#ffffffff</color>
<color name="news_card_ripple_material_light">#ffffcc80</color>
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you try setting android:radius = -1 for the ripple...

Comment: Hi, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of a ripple on Android M and up.
You can see this in Google now cards for example